# Transfer file from persistent storage to android

Tags: tails, android

I've tried installing Termux on my smartphone and using netcat to transfer the file but it didn't work.

Is there an easier way? Or maybe I can transfer the file to an USB stick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access an Android device from Tails with `adb` and a special rule for `iptables`:

```
iptables -I OUTPUT -d localhost -o lo -p tcp --dport 5037 -m owner --uid-owner amnesia -j ACCEPT
```

Source: https://roneo.org/en/android-setup-adb-tails/